# Why small data size cause GC overhead limit exception?

Tags: java, python, apache-spark, garbage-collection

I use spark doing some calculation. 
Basically I did two thing:

1. New file will come into a folder periodically
2. I turn the new files into data frame then insert it into an previous data frame.

(You may ask why I read it in loop. I did it because of some reasons:
1. The files not comes at once. Actually it will come periodically. So I can not read them at once.
2. Although Stream can do this. I do not want to use stream. Because using Stream I need to set up a long window. It is not convienent to debug and test 
)

The code is like below :

```
# Get the file list in the HDFS directory
client = InsecureClient('http://10.79.148.184:50070')
file_list = client.list('/test')

df_total = None
counter = 0
for file in file_list:
    counter += 1

    # turn each file (CSV format) into data frame
    lines = sc.textFile("/test/%s" % file)
    parts = lines.map(lambda l: l.split(","))
    rows = parts.map(lambda p: Row(router=p[0], interface=int(p[1]), protocol=p[7],bit=int(p[10])))
    df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rows)

    # do some transform on the data frame
    df_protocol = df.groupBy(['protocol']).agg(func.sum('bit').alias('bit'))

    # add the current data frame to previous data frame set
    if not df_total:
        df_total = df_protocol
    else:
        df_total = df_total.unionAll(df_protocol)

    # cache the df_total
    df_total.cache()
    if counter % 5 == 0:
        df_total.rdd.checkpoint()

    # get the df_total information
    df_total.show()
```

I know that as time goes on, the df_total could be big. But actually, before that time come, the above code already raise exception.

When the loop is about 30 loops. The code throw GC overhead limit exceeded exception. The file is very small so even 300 loops the data size could only be about a few MB. I do not know why it throw GC error.

The exception detail is below ：

```
Exception in thread "dispatcher-event-loop-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.lang.Integer.toString(Integer.java:331)
    at java.lang.Integer.toString(Integer.java:739)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2854)
    at scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.RDDBlockId.name(BlockId.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockId.equals(BlockId.scala:46)
    at java.util.HashMap.getEntry(HashMap.java:471)
    at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:421)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.org$apache$spark$storage$BlockManagerMasterEndpoint$$getLocations(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:371)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$storage$BlockManagerMasterEndpoint$$getLocationsMultipleBlockIds$1.apply(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:376)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$storage$BlockManagerMasterEndpoint$$getLocationsMultipleBlockIds$1.apply(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:376)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.org$apache$spark$storage$BlockManagerMasterEndpoint$$getLocationsMultipleBlockIds(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:376)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint$$anonfun$receiveAndReply$1.applyOrElse(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcV$sp(Inbox.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.safelyCall(Inbox.scala:204)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.process(Inbox.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher$MessageLoop.run(Dispatcher.scala:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
16/04/20 09:52:00 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 0 on ES01: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
16/04/20 09:52:12 ERROR TransportRequestHandler: Error sending result RpcResponse{requestId=4721950849479578179, body=NioManagedBuffer{buf=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=47 cap=47]}} to ES01/10.79.148.184:53059; closing connection
io.netty.handler.codec.EncoderException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write(MessageToMessageEncoder.java:107)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:633)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:691)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:626)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.write(IdleStateHandler.java:284)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:633)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1900(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:32)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:908)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$WriteAndFlushTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:960)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:893)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena$HeapArena.newChunk(PoolArena.java:602)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocateNormal(PoolArena.java:228)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocate(PoolArena.java:204)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocate(PoolArena.java:132)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.newHeapBuffer(PooledByteBufAllocator.java:256)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.heapBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:136)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.heapBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:127)
    at org.apache.spark.network.protocol.MessageEncoder.encode(MessageEncoder.java:77)
    at org.apache.spark.network.protocol.MessageEncoder.encode(MessageEncoder.java:33)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write(MessageToMessageEncoder.java:89)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: Seems issue is coming from first 3 lines of code rather then from loop itself.

Comment: @TyagiAkhilesh what is the problem with first 3 lines of code? can you give more details please

Comment: Why do you you even read this in loop?

Comment: @zero323 Because the files comes not at once. They comes in one by one with time. So I have to read them one by one

Comment: So what is the configuration here?

Comment: @zero323 by configuration. You mean memory setting? I assign 4GB memory to worker and 4GB to driver. But the total size of data is less than 8mb